# unison over ssh with white spaces in directories

Tags: unison

I want to do something like this

`unison 192.168.1.1:/data/<example directory>   /data/server_backup`

There is a space in the source directory. Is there some way I can do this with out using "\"

Answer (score 1):

you can try using this -> " . like `ip:"path1 with whitespace" /path2`